# How to interpret the results of multcompLetters in R (clustering of groups using posthoc Tukey test results)

Tags: r, bioinformatics, anova

I am new to statistics and I am trying to conduct an analysis in `R` on data containing read count information for 45 samples. I carried out an `ANOVA` (using the `aov()` function), comparing the means of each sample, and have also run a `post-hoc` `Tukey` test (using the `TukeyHSD(`) function).

I have used the `multcompLetters()` function from the '`multcompView`' package to cluster the samples into groups that differ significantly based on the result of the `Tukey` test. It has produced a list of groups named 'a', 'ab' and 'b'.

I understand that the samples assigned to group 'a' are significantly different from those assigned to group 'b', but I was hoping someone might be able to help me understand what it means when a sample is assigned the 'ab' group?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Groups assigned 'ab' are not significantly different from groups assigned 'a' or groups assigned 'b'.